# Disabling expiry check in simple-jwt package

Tags: python-3.x, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

We previously used the following setting in django-rest-framework-jwt package to disable token expiration check:

```
'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': False
```

However now we are using django-rest-framework-simplejwt for authentication. How can we disable the expiry check in this package? I want to make sure that none of the existing tokens are invalidated because they are expired.